# show $b_1 = \frac{\sum X_i Y_i}{\sum X_i^2} $ from least square formula

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

$$\begin{aligned}
b_1 &= \frac{n(\sum{x_i y_i) }-(\sum{y_i})( \sum{x_i})}{n\sum x^2_i-(\sum x_i )^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Leting $$\begin{aligned}
              X_i &=X_i - \bar X= x_i -\frac{\sum x_i}{n }
           \\ Y_i &=y_i-\bar y=y_i -\frac{\sum y_i}{n}
      \end{aligned}$$
$$ \begin{aligned}
b_1&= \text{missing steps}
\\ &= 
\\ &=\frac{\sum X_i Y_i}{\sum X_i^2}
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: You might want to modify the clashing notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to simplify the sums. Thus, 
$$\frac{\sum{X_iY_i}}{\sum{X_i^2}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{(nx_i-n\bar{x})(ny_i-n\bar{y})}}{\sum_{i=1}^n(nx_i-n\bar{x})^2}\\ =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i}-\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{i=1}^n{\bar{x}\bar{y}}}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\bar{x}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{x}^2}\\ =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i}-n\bar{x}\bar{y}-n\bar{y}\bar{x}+n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2n\bar{x}^2+n\bar{x}^2}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i}-n\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-n\bar{x}^2}=b_1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}$

> $\ds{b_{1} \equiv
> {n\sum_{i}x_{i}y_{i} - \pars{\sum_{i}{y_{i}}}\pars{\sum_{i}{x_{i}}}
> \over n\sum_{i}x_{i}^{2} - \pars{\sum_{i}x_{i}}^{2}}
> \implies b_{1} = {\sum_{i}X_{i}Y_{i} \over \sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}}\quad\mbox{where}\quad
> \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{X_{i}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{x_{i} - {1 \over n}\sum_{j}x_{j}}
> \\
> \ds{Y_{i}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{y_{i} - {1 \over n}\sum_{j}y_{j}}
> \end{array}\right.}$

We'll use the 'comfortable' notation $\ds{\avg{f} = {1 \over n}\sum_{i}f_{i}}$ such that the above statement is rewritten as:
$$\bbx{\ds{%
b_{1} \equiv
{\avg{xy} - \avg{y}\avg{x} \over \avg{x^{2}} - \avg{x}^{2}}
\implies b_{1} =
{\avg{XY} \over \avg{X^{2}}}\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{X_{i}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{x_{i} - \avg{x}}
\\
\ds{Y_{i}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{y_{i} - \avg{y}}
\\[2mm] &&
\color{#f00}{\mbox{Note that}\ \ds{\avg{X} = \avg{Y} = 0}}
\end{array}\right.}}
$$

---

\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\avg{xy}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{i}\pars{X_{i} + \avg{x}}\pars{Y_{i} + \avg{y}}}
\\ & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{i}\pars{\vphantom{\Large A}%
X_{i}Y_{i} + \avg{y}X_{i} + \avg{x}Y_{i} + \avg{x}\avg{y}}}
\\ & \ds{=} &
\ds{\avg{XY} + \avg{y}\avg{X} + \avg{x}\avg{Y} + \avg{x}\avg{y} =
\bbx{\ds{\avg{XY} + \avg{x}\avg{y}}}}
\\[1cm]
\ds{\avg{x^{2}}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{i}\pars{X_{i} + \avg{x}}^{2} =
\avg{X^{2}} + 2\avg{X}\avg{x} + \avg{x}^{2} =
\bbx{\ds{\avg{X^{2}} + \avg{x}^{2}}}}
\end{array}\right.
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
With the above expressions it's clear that:
$$\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px groove navy]{\ds{%
b_{i}  =
{n\sum_{i}x_{i}y_{i} - \pars{\sum_{i}{y_{i}}}\pars{\sum_{i}{x_{i}}}
\over n\sum_{i}x_{i}^{2} - \pars{\sum_{i}x_{i}}^{2}}
={\avg{XY} \over \avg{X^{2}}} =
{\sum_{i}X_{i}Y_{i} \over \sum_{i}X_{i}^{2}}}}
$$
because $\pars{~\mbox{see expressions}\ \eqref{1}~}$
$\ds{\quad\avg{xy} - \avg{y}\avg{x} = \avg{XY}\quad}$ and
$\ds{\quad\avg{x^{2}} - \avg{x}^{2} = \avg{X^{2}}}$.